# The shape of convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

The definition of a convex function is as follows.
The line segment connecting any two points on the graph is above the graph.
But with this definition, I don't know why the convex function is U-shaped.
I know that a U-shaped function satisfies this definition. but the converse.
Why is the convex function U-shaped?

Comment: Are you looking for an intuitive explanation or a detailed proof?  If the latter, you will need to define precisely what you mean by "U-shaped".

Comment: Do you consider $f(x)=x$ as $U-$shaped?

Comment: Yes. f(x) = |x| is also convex.

Comment: @David I want an explanation.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by $U-$ shaped. As it stands the question does not make much sense (since you cannot prove the converse part or give a counter-example without knowing what $U-$ shaped means.

Comment: I know that as the tangent slope of a differentiable convex function increases, it draws a U-shape.

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function In simple terms, a convex function refers to a function whose graph is shaped like a cup {\displaystyle \cup }\cup , while a concave function's graph is shaped like a cap {\displaystyle \cap }\cap .

Answer (score 0):

Given a sufficiently broad definition of what counts as "U-shaped", then it might be best to think in terms of "What happens if a function *isn't* U-shaped?".

If the function fails to be U-shaped, i.e. some of the function bends back on itself, then you can choose two points on either side of that bend and the line between them will have to cross over the bendy part of the function, which means that the function cannot be convex.